# how to get zeus to boot passenger standalone by default instead of webrick?

Tags: passenger, zeus

Upon starting zeus & running zeus s, rails server boots with  the default WEBrick web server. How can zeus be customized so that it boots passenger standalone by default. 
(I have passenger standalone working in development environment, i can boot it with 'bundle exec passenger start' from the command line or with a hack to script bin/rails which defaults rails s to start with passenger.)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to achieving this is to use guard, guard-passenger in combination with zeus.
guard-passenger gem is available at https://github.com/guard/guard-passenger
start zeus first and then start guard which will now automatically boot a rails server using passenger standalone configured in the app.